# Javascript ReferenceError: min is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to wrap my head around anonymous and named functions and I have this Javascript code here:

```
travelNode = min = function(travelNode) {
      console.log(travelNode);
      if(travelNode.left === null) 
           return travelNode;
      else 
           return min(travelNode.left);
}(travelNode.right);
```

When I try and run this block, I get a `ReferenceError: min is not defined`. However, when I change the code to this:

```
travelNode = function min(travelNode) {
      console.log(travelNode);
      if(travelNode.left === null) 
           return travelNode;
      else 
           return min(travelNode.left);
}(travelNode.right);
```

and it works just fine.

Obviously, the first one uses anonymous functions and the second a named function. However, why does the second one work but the first one doesn't? How would I fix the first one?

Edit: Here's the entire code block -

```
delete: function(data) {
        var deleteHelper = function(travelNode) {
            if(travelNode === null)
                return null;
            if(data < travelNode.data)
                travelNode.left = deleteHelper(travelNode.left);
            else if(data > travelNode.data)
                travelNode.right = deleteHelper(travelNode.right);
            else {
                if(travelNode.right === null)
                    return travelNode.left;
                else if(travelNode.left === null)
                    return travelNode.right;
                travelNode = min = function(travelNode) {
                    console.log(travelNode);
                    if(travelNode.left === null) 
                        return travelNode;
                    else 
                        return min(travelNode.left);
                }(travelNode.right);
            }
            return travelNode;
        };
        this.root = deleteHelper(this.root);
    }
```

Comment: Where are `travelNode` and `min` declared? Can you post a demo to reproduce the problem?

Comment: `var min;
 travelNode = min = function(travelNode) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var g = function f() { ... }` will scope `f` inside the function (so it is undefined outside it); it will be assigned to `g` outside it (which has scope over the insides of it). As a result, you can call the function `f` inside, and `g` both inside and outside. `f` is safe from tampering, since it only has value in the closure; while `g` can be redefined, potentially breaking your code.

In your second example, `min` is defined inside the function (but not outside it); since you use it inside but not outside, everything works.

In your first example, you make an anonymous function. Then you invoke it with `(travelNode.right)`. The function executes, and breaks (since `min` is not yet assigned). If the function were to complete without error, the return value would have been assigned to both `min` and `travelNode` (just like `y = x = Math.sqrt(4)` assigns `2` to `x` and also `y` *after* evaluating `Math.sqrt`).

You could use parentheses, and make it work:

```
travelNode = (min = function(travelNode) {
      console.log(travelNode);
      if(travelNode.left === null) 
           return travelNode;
      else 
           return min(travelNode.left);
})(travelNode.right);
```

Here, you construct an anonymous function, assign its value to `min`, then invoke it; since `min` is assigned and in scope, it still works.

Arguably, your second approach is the best, given that you only use `min` from inside; it also has an added benefit for debugging, since the function will not show up as anonymous in stack traces.